# Unable to get clearRect to work with rotation and arc

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I am trying to animate a small dot along a curved path using a HTML5 Canvas. The animation i have working but i cannot get the clearRect to work so each frame is just stacking on top of the next.

Here is the drawing code, can2 and ctx2 are global variable set in the .ready function of the page.

```js
function drawTempStep(){
    //Clear the Canvas
    ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, can2.width, can2.height);
    ctx2.save();
    //Check we're centered
    ctx2.moveTo(0, 0);
    //Rotate Canvas so we are drawing strait
    ctx2.rotate(getRadians(canvasRotation));
    //Begin new Path
    //Create reflection for the dot
    //First create gradiated fill style
    var grd = ctx2.createRadialGradient(0, weatherDivSize.width / 2 * .70, 0, 0, weatherDivSize.width / 2 * .70, weatherDivSize.width*.2);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(176,0,0,0.2)");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    //Now beging the path
    ctx2.beginPath();
    //Draw the Arc
    ctx2.arc(0, weatherDivSize.width / 2 * .70, weatherDivSize.width*.2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx2.closePath();
    //Fille and stroke it
    ctx2.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx2.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    //Now lets draw the smaller inner circle
    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.arc(0, weatherDivSize.width / 2 * .70, weatherDivSize.width*.009, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx2.closePath();
    ctx2.fillStyle = '#B00000';
    ctx2.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    //Return the canvas rotation to it's starting point
    ctx2.rotate(-getRadians(canvasRotation));
    //All done so restore the context to it's previous state
    ctx2.restore();
}
```

Here is a link to the the full project on CodePen so you can see what's going on.

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/gazzer82/full/jPROKB)

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: I'm stuck at a sort of loading with a spinner, is it normal ? Is it what you want to animate ?

Comment: Sorry i'm working on other parts of it and you probably hit it when i had JS error. However, i've worked out the problem, i have a translate going on in the .ready that was moving 0,0 to the centre of the canvas, and the thing i was trying to clear is in the left of the canvas, so it wasn't getting cleared. So set a transform to get everything back to top left for the clearRect and i'm in business.

Comment: That's a really sexy widget, kudos on your design.

Comment: Thanks, it's one of the Ziplines on freecodecamp, second thing i've made :)